# TextView not being centered

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="com.example.fake9.tendee.SettingsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Decription"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_edit_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/settings_description"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_edit_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/settings_address"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/settings_edit_description"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EditPassBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Change Password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I center the text in the TextView in the center? The others are working but not the center one. I have added the same tags I have added for the other textviews.  I would like all the text here to be centered.

The pictures to the right of the text are also textviews. I'm not sure what more I can do as all the tags are the same.

Comment: The image and the information contained therein is unnecessary to your question, at least as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="com.example.fake9.tendee.SettingsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_email"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Decription"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EditPassBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Change Password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This fixed the layout but somehow the on click functionality of the TextView with the edit image is not working.

Comment: You need to add DrawableClickListener to the textview. for click events.

Comment: I am currently using setOnClickListener on the textView and it used to work. Is DrawableClickListener better?

Comment: Previously, you were using two textviews. One for text, and one for drawable. But in real, you vcan use a textview with a drawable and add click listener to both textview as well as its drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="com.example.fake9.tendee.SettingsActivity">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/settings_display_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Decription"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:text="Address"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_edit_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/settings_description"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/settings_description"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settings_edit_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/settings_address"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/settings_edit_description"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/EditPassBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="Change Password"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```